# Adding a column to the `2D ArrayList`

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to figure out how to add an additional column in the far right of the `2D ArrayList` with no luck. My method, `addCol()` runs the loop infinitely with no stop. I have the following:

```
BAC
BEC
BEA
BAB
```

But why is my method running infinitely. I've included my `toString()` method too, in any case.

Class **Tester**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[][] myString = {{"A", "B", "C"}, {"A", "A", "A"}, {"B", "A", "C"}, {"B", "E", "C"}, {"B", "E", "A"}, {"B", "A", "B"}};

    //  board.addRow();
        board.addCol();
        System.out.println(board);
    }
}
```

Class **Board**

```
     private ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> myBoard = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
     public String toString(){
          String result = "";
          for(int i = 0; i < myBoard.size(); i++){

              }
              result += "\n";
          }

          return result;
      }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `e` parameter to the constructor?

Answer (score 3):

The loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < myBoard.size(); i++){
    myBoard.add(col);
}
```

is not what you meant. Every iteration, you add to `myBoard`, so `myBoard.size()` increases by `1` and `i` never catches up with it.

You must mean something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < myBoard.size(); i++){
    myBoard.get(i).add(null);
}
```

or, even better

```
for (List<T> list : myBoard)
    list.add(null);
```

Comment: WOW, all the other answers totally missed the point of the initial flaw with creating a new ArrayList when adding a column. This answer is exactly what I would have written. +10 up-votes from me *(wish I could)*.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void addCol(){
          ArrayList<T> col = new ArrayList<T>();

          for(int i = 0; i < myBoard.size(); i++){
              myBoard.add(col);
          }  
      }
```

Look carefully at your method. You adding a row and not a column where `myBoard` is a list of `ArrayList`.

You need to modify your method such that. Please follow comments

```
 public void addCol(){
              ArrayList<T> row = new ArrayList<T>();// row

              T t = new T();   // column
              T t2 = new T();// column    
              row.add(t)/ adding column

              row.add(t2)/ adding another column and so on
              myBoard.add(row); // now adding whole row to myBoard

              for(int i = 0; i < myBoard.size(); i++){
                  myBoard.add(col);
              }  
          }
```

That will add columns right away. And if you want to add to specific row, you need to know the index before in hand

```
public void addCol(int index ){
      T col = new T();// create or receive in method params           
      myBoard.get(index).add(col); 
  }
```

Comment: @SureshAtta, but how could you instantiate `T t = new T()` ?

Comment: @John I mean the type. No exactly `T`

Comment: @SureshAtta, when I try in Eclipse, it says cannot instantiate the type T

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < myBoard.size(); i++){
          myBoard.get(index).add(col);
      } ` 

will break the code with indexOutOfBounds exception

Comment: @AlvaroJoao Exactly, if OP know index, directly he can add to that row as a column.

Comment: Down-vote: Your code still has the original never-ending add-row-to-board loop. The code is malformed (missing semi-colons and comments starting with a single slash). Even fixing that, neither method will compile. The alternate at the bottom would add a new column to *one* row, but the board is a 2D matrix, so all rows must be same size.